# In excel: How to determine if 01/01/1900 then print out empty string, otherwise show the date

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I'm trying to show all dates except for 01/01/1900. In excel, how do I first check for 01/01/1900 and then replace only that date with empty string or "", but leave any other dates alone?  I also need to keep the format set to small date format of mm/dd/yyyy.

I tried to use replace, if, date, datevalue commands without successs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new column next to your column with dates, and use this formula for every cell (*A1* here refers to the source cell):

> =IF(A1<>DATE(1900,1,1),A1,"")

Then format your new column as a date.

Answer (score 14):

Another answer which does not affect your data, but only the *presentation* layer is to set up a custom formatting.  Choose the cells you want, and press CTRL+1 or choose Format Cells from the Format menu.  Then under number format, Date should be selected.  Click on Custom at the bottom of the list, then add two semicolons after the formatting string picture that is there.

A custom formatting string can have three (sometimes four) pictures seperated by semicolons.  The first is for positive numbers, the second for negative, and the third for zero.

My formatting string looks like this: 'm/d/yyyy;;'.  All zero dates (1/0/1900) will be blank.   No extra column needed.

Comment: Its not working on excel 2010 for me either.  Do you have to select "Custom"?  I tried custom, and entired m/d/yyyy;;  that is two semicolons on the end at it still has the original date applied.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  That is what I get for not actually checking my work before posting it!  My answer is just a specific (and easy) way of doing conditional formatting, which I think is better if the behavior required is only in the presentation and not in the data layer.